# libiconv.2.dylib Mac OS X Problem

Tags: macos, libiconv

I have a problem with the important file libiconv.2.dylib. When I want to start some applications (like macvim, etc.) i get this error:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap
```

Is there any way to restore (no time machine available) or recompile this library for Mac (10.6)?

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib` and `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have a mismatch between architectures.  The system library `libiconv` should be a universal file that contains all necessary archs; on OS X 10.6, Apple ships it with three.

```
$ file /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (for architecture ppc7400):   Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
```

Try something similar for the MacVim.app executable:

```
$ file /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

There needs to be at least one common architecture and the app needs to be running in one of those common archs.  Make sure you have a current version of the app.  If the `libiconv` does not have all of those architectures, your system installation of OS X 10.6 is faulty.  Perhaps you tried to install something into `/usr/lib`?  Don't do that.  If so, you may need to carefully reinstall OS X 10.6.